# select rows with the same column values

Tags: mysql

Given the table structure below, how do I select only rows having the same root and level values for a given name and user_id?

```
    Category
    +----+---------+------+------+-------+
    | id | user_id | name | root | level |
    +----+---------+------+------+-------+
    |  1 |      10 | wzq  |    1 |     1 |
    |  2 |      11 | xyz  |    2 |     1 |
    |  3 |      10 | xyz  |    2 |     2 |
    |  4 |      10 | xyz  |    2 |     2 |
    +----+---------+------+------+-------+
```

What I have now also selects rows that do not have the same root and level

```
SELECT `c`.`id`, `c`.`user_id`, `c`.`name`, `c`.`root`, `c`.`level`
FROM `category` `c`
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT d.id FROM category AS d WHERE c.root=d.root AND c.level=d.level ) AND c.user_id = 10 AND c.name = 'xyz'
ORDER BY `c`.`id`
```

For the above example only the 3rd and 4th rows should be returned

Comment: It will help if you could post expected result.

Comment: Could you give an example what your expected output should be?

Comment: All user_ids (and names) are the same. Is that intentional?

Comment: Shouldn't be the first row selected? it has `root` = `level` too?

Comment: No, the root and level value of each row compared to the root and level values of other rows should be the same not the same row

Answer (score 1):

Try this one  for *select only rows having the same root and level* simply `root=level`

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `name`, `root`, `level`
FROM `category` 
WHERE root=level  AND user_id = 10 AND `name` = 'xyz'
ORDER BY `id`
```

Comment: Well, that's one interpretation!

Comment: This is returning the first row, as the description of the OP it should only return the 3th and 4th only, see [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d89e/4)

Comment: I agree, the OP's example is extremely confusing. But this is not what they meant.

Comment: @Strawberry I also agree.

Comment: I agree with you all but in first glance OP asked for *select only rows having the same root and level* and then a contradicting thing he asked for 3rd 4th row

Comment: He meant where root=root and level=level, not root=level

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.root = x.root 
   AND y.level = x.level 
   AND y.id <> x.id
 WHERE x.user_id = 10
```

Comment: this returns duplicates, adding DISTINCT might be the right answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT root, level
    FROM category 
    WHERE name = 'xyz' AND user_id = 10
) x JOIN category c ON x.root = c.root
```